# Dynamic css class attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, struts2

I have a navigation bar whose elements are rendered using Struts2 `iterator` tag like below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<s:iterator var="row" value="#session.PrivMenu.children" status="stat">         
    <li>
        <a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu<s:property value="#stat.index+1"/>">
            <s:property value="#row.moduleName"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</s:iterator>  

</ul>
```

Now I have to apply an **icon** with each `<a>` element. Since the icon is going to be different for each navbar element, a different styling will be required for each `<a>` tag.

How can I achieve this in struts2 ??

I thought of dynamic `cssClass` attribute.

```
cssClass = '<s:property value="#row.moduleName"/>' + icon
```

But I think like this later if module name changes, I will have to edit my css too. Am I going wrong??? Any better idea?

Comment: from what html to what html you want....

Comment: Anchor tags rendered by the iterator tag.

Comment: The question is misasked. WHY and HOW the moduleName will eventually change the name ? Will it be the same module with a different name ? Will it be a new Module ? The number of modules will never change ? Are the images inside the war or stored externally ? Are the CSS inside the war or stored externally ? And so on... please clarify your question to get a better help

Comment: Do you want to click on image or title?

Comment: Title and the icon will remain in background

Comment: Would you post an image that correspond to the design of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to work with nth-child, it's not working for browsers like ie8 or less.
Another possibilty (if the menu structure does not change) is using a unique class with a counter on the li.

Then use correct css to design the menu

If you have a possibilty of using a counter you can use is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <s:iterator var="row" value="#session.PrivMenu.children" status="stat">
    <li class="menu-2"><a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu<s:property value="#stat.index+1"/>">
      <s:property value="#row.moduleName"/></a>
    </li>                       
  </s:iterator>
  <s:iterator var="row" value="#session.PrivMenu.children" status="stat">
    <li class="menu-3"><a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu<s:property value="#stat.index+1"/>">
      <s:property value="#row.moduleName"/></a>
    </li>                       
  </s:iterator>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a class to it and then use css to add an icon. In your css you can use the 'nth-child' selector to add different icons to each a tag.

See: w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp for more info on that.

Using the selector you can set the background for each a tag. Example: if you have 7 links and want to set the 5th background use:

`.MyNavBar a:nth-child(7n+5) {width: 50px;background-image:url('MyImageurl');}`